# Undefined reference when using intrinsic

Tags: intel, intrinsics, intel-mic

I want to test the SIMD intrinsic of xeon phi. So I wrote following code:

```
#pragma offload target(mic) in(a:length(N))
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0;i<16;++i){
    __m512i p ;
    p = _mm512_loadunpackhi_epi64(p, &a[i*10]);
}
```

When compiling, `icpc` gave me undefined reference error

```
/tmp/icpc3kLMRg.o: In function `main':
./src/test.cc:(.text+0x2e8): undefined reference to `_mm512_extloadunpackhi_epi64'
make: *** [test.cc] Error 1
```

Is there any other header files to be included besides `immintrin.h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler compiles for the host as well as for the xeon phi. The host doesn't support the function you are trying to call so you need to do this:

```
#ifdef __MIC__
#pragma offload target(mic) in(a:length(N))
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0;i<16;++i){
    __m512i p ;
    p = _mm512_loadunpackhi_epi64(p, &a[i*10]);
}
#else
   <do something differnt on the host (or nothing)>
#endif
```